# How can I design a select statement to select a subset of values exclusively based on a condition?

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, sql-server-2014, case-when

I'm trying to design an SQL statement to select values only in certain cases. Here is an example to illustrate my 2 input tables and expected output.

**Table1:**

```
TransactionID   TotalItemsType1 TotalItemsType2
0001            1               8
0002            7               6
1234            5               6
```

**Table2:**

```
TransactionID   Cost
0001            5.99
1234            2.25
1234            0.15
0002            9.99
```

**Expected Result:**

```
TransactionID   Cost    TotalItemsType1 TotalItemsType2
0001            5.99    1               8
0002            9.99    7               6
1234            2.25    5               6
1234            0.15    0               0
```

When there are multiple rows in Table2 for a single TransactionID (1234), the TotalItemsType1/2 columns in the output should be populated only for the TransactionID with the highest Cost value (2.25 compared to 0.15), otherwise returning 0. In the case of a multiple equal highest values (2.25 compared to 2.25 for example) then just choose one of the TransactionIDs based on database row order (first).

I've attempted to do this using various joins and case expressions but I haven't yet found a workable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a partitioned row number to Table2 via a CTE, and then conditionally use values from the JOIN only if the row number is 1 (and 0 otherwise):

```
WITH rn AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TransactionID ORDER BY Cost) rn
  FROM Table2
)
SELECT rn.TransactionID, rn.Cost, COALESCE(t1.TotalItemsType1, 0) TotalItemsType1,
       COALESCE(t1.TotalItemsType2, 0) TotalItemsType2
FROM rn LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
  ON rn.TransactionID = t1.TransactionID AND rn.rn = 1
```

The `LEFT JOIN` uses a condition of the row number being 1 to generate "empty columns" for Table1 where it's not 1. Then the `COALESCE` uses these NULL values to generate the required 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
with max_cost as ( select transactionid tranid,max(cost) max_cost1 from tran_2 group by transactionid)
select a.transactionid,
       b.cost,
       decode(b.cost,max_cost1,a.totaltype1,0) type_1,
       decode(b.cost,max_cost1,a.totaltype2,0) type_2
from tran_1 a,tran_2 b,max_cost c 
where a.transactionid = b.transactionid 
and c.tranid = a.transactionid 
and c.tranid = b.transactionid 
order by a.transactionid
```

solution without using analytic function
i have used the tran_1 table containing transactionid,type1,type2 column
and tran_2 table containing transactionid,cost